# For an accessible HTML table that has form inputs in the table cells (buttons, links), best practices for tab and arrow key behavior?

Tags: accessibility

I am building HTML pages with tables that contain form inputs in the cells (e.g., buttons, text boxes) in one or two columns of the table.  I need this page and table to be (508) Accessible.  What is the best practice for navigation of such a table (with "editable" inputs) regarding tabs and arrow keys?  Should the tab key press navigate into the table, but the arrow keys navigate within the table?  Should the tab key press navigate into, within, then to outside the table?  If the tab key is doing the navigation, should the arrow keys also do navigation inside the table?

Comment: Do you have an example page? It will be easier to answer with a concrete example of what you are going to do. There are several possible ways to approach your question, depending on the content to be filled and the typical order in which it is filled.

Answer (score 2):

The [WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices 1.1 guide for data grids](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#grid) has the following recommendations:

> - Right Arrow: Moves focus one cell to the right. If focus is on the right-most cell in the row, focus does not move.
> - Left Arrow: Moves focus one cell to the left. If focus is on the left-most cell in the row, focus does not move.
> - Down Arrow: Moves focus one cell down. If focus is on the bottom cell in the column, focus does not move.
> - Up Arrow: Moves focus one cell Up. If focus is on the top cell in the column, focus does not move.
> - Page Down: Moves focus down an author-determined number of rows, typically scrolling so the bottom row in the currently visible set of
>     rows becomes one of the first visible rows. If focus is in the last
>     row of the grid, focus does not move.
> - Page Up: Moves focus up an author-determined number of rows, typically scrolling so the top row in the currently visible set of
>     rows becomes one of the last visible rows. If focus is in the first
>     row of the grid, focus does not move.
> - Home: moves focus to the first cell in the row that contains focus.
> - End: moves focus to the last cell in the row that contains focus.
> - Control + Home: moves focus to the first cell in the first row.
> - Control + End: moves focus to the last cell in the last row.

Comment: Thanks for forwarding those guidelines.  They seem like the appropriate guidelines for the "grid" we are putting together.

Comment: The address for those guidelines seems to have changed: https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/grid/